# Cancel the entered data in the calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

At the moment, there is a calendar on my site where the user can select a time range and data filtering will be done. For this I use the react-advanced-datetimerange-picker library.

But there is one drawback. You cannot cancel the selected data without reloading the page.
Please tell me how to make a button (example near close button) that will allow you to reset the entered filters and get the entire list of data again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function called `resetDate` which when clicked return the Calendar to its initial value, please check.

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-architecture-9v7e84

Comment: Can this button be placed in a modal window?

Comment: Do you mean in Calednar itself?

Comment: Yes, next to (or instead of) the close button

Comment: It isn't supported in the library too, but I made a trick which add event listener to the close button when you click it, the date will be reset.